# Pivot/crosstab data on multiple columns with order in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, crosstab

Is it possible to get a cross-tab table with multiple values in the rows and specify an order for those rows and columns?

The cross-tab I need is frequency.

If I have a data frame like

```
name    abbr    itemGroup
abcd    a       g1
abcd    a       g2
bcde    b       g1
bcde    b       g2
abcd    a       g3
abcd    a       g1
bcde    b       g2
bcde    b       g2
bcde    b       g2
```

How can I get result crosstab table like this? Where rows are ordered, descending, by the total of each row and the columns are ordered, descending left-to-right, by the total in each column.

```
name   abbr    g2   g1   g3  total
bcde   b       4    1    0   5
abcd   a       1    2    1   4
TOTAL          5    3    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complicated `tidyverse` approach.

```
library(tidyverse) #for dplyr, purrr, tibble, tidyr

df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~abbr, ~itemGroup,
  "abcd",    "a",       "g1",
  "abcd",    'a',       "g2",
  "bcde",    "b",       "g1",
  "bcde",    "b",       "g2",
  "abcd",    "a",       "g3",
  "abcd",    "a",       "g1",
  "bcde",    "b",       "g2",
  "bcde",    "b",       "g2",
  "bcde",    "b",       "g2"
)

order <- count(df, name, abbr, itemGroup) %>%
  group_by(itemGroup) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(n)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  pull(itemGroup)


df %>%
  count(name, abbr, itemGroup) %>%
  spread(itemGroup, n) %>%
  left_join(group_by(df, name, abbr) %>%
     summarize(total = n())) %>%
  bind_rows(summarize_at(., vars(contains("g")), funs(sum), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
              mutate(name = "TOTAL")) %>%
  map_df(~replace(.x, is.na(.x), "")) %>%
  arrange(desc(total)) %>% 
  select(name, abbr, one_of(order), total)
```

Results in:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
   name  abbr    g2    g1    g3 total
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1  bcde     b     4     1           5
2  abcd     a     1     2     1     4
3 TOTAL           5     3     1
```

1. The second bit, after defining df, determines the column order of the row total.
2. This counts each item, spreads it into columns, joins in the column total, binds the row summary, replaces `NA` with "", arranges the total column and selects the proper order of the remaining columns.

Comment: Gah! tidyverse won't install due to a compile error in mnormt

Comment: A compiler change to gforgran and gcc 5 made the difference

Comment: I had to go one step further to get the sort rows to properly work `outData$total<-as.numeric(outData$total)` then `outData<-outData %>% arrange(desc(total))` again.  Otherwise a record with 999 items was ahead of a record of 10000 items.